# Populate a list with combinations of one- and two- object functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

I have a nested set of `for` loops which achieves the desired outcome, but I don't know if it is the most efficient / pythonic way of populating this list.

I would like all combinations of the one object functions, combined with 0 to n combinations of the two object function.

Here, I have abstracted parts of the code away so we are only dealing with the loops:

```py
import itertools as it

# Define arbitrary functions that act on two objects and single objects
def two_obj_fn(a, b):
    return 'two_obj_fn({}, {})'.format(a , b)

def A(a):
    return 'A({})'.format(a)

def B(b):
    return 'B({})'.format(b)

def C(c):
    return 'C({})'.format(c)

a = 'a'
b = 'b'

objects = [a, b]

n = len(objects)

two_obj_fns_coupled = set(two_obj_fn(first, second) for first, second in
                          it.zip_longest(objects, objects[1:], fillvalue=objects[0]))

single_obj_fns = {A, B, C}
single_fns_combinations = it.combinations_with_replacement(single_obj_fns, n)

double_fns_combinations = set()
for i in range(len(two_obj_fns_coupled) + 1):
    double_fns_combinations.update(it.combinations(two_obj_fns_coupled, i))

out = []
for combo in single_fns_combinations:
    if not combo.count(A) % 2 == 0:
         if not combo.count(C) == n:
             for permutation in it.permutations(combo):
                 for double_fns in double_fns_combinations :
                     single_fns_string = [fn(objects[i])for i, fn in
                                          enumerate(permutation)]

                     single_fns_string.extend(double_fns)
                     out.append(tuple(single_fns_string))

out = tuple(out)
```

I know that this blows up with the addition of more objects, but for the two objects a and b this gives the desired result of (linebreaks added for clarity):

```
(
('A(a)', 'B(b)', 'two_obj_fn(b, a)'),
('A(a)', 'B(b)'), 
('A(a)', 'B(b)', 'two_obj_fn(a, b)'), 
('A(a)', 'B(b)', 'two_obj_fn(a, b)', 'two_obj_fn(b, a)'), 
('B(a)', 'A(b)', 'two_obj_fn(b, a)'), 
('B(a)', 'A(b)'), 
('B(a)', 'A(b)', 'two_obj_fn(a, b)'), 
('B(a)', 'A(b)', 'two_obj_fn(a, b)', 'two_obj_fn(b, a)'), 
('A(a)', 'C(b)', 'two_obj_fn(b, a)'), 
('A(a)', 'C(b)'), 
('A(a)', 'C(b)', 'two_obj_fn(a, b)'), 
('A(a)', 'C(b)', 'two_obj_fn(a, b)', 'two_obj_fn(b, a)'), 
('C(a)', 'A(b)', 'two_obj_fn(b, a)'), 
('C(a)', 'A(b)'), 
('C(a)', 'A(b)', 'two_obj_fn(a, b)'), 
('C(a)', 'A(b)', 'two_obj_fn(a, b)', 'two_obj_fn(b, a)')
)
```

I would really appreciate some guidance on this, as I know it could get slow very quickly. Everything above and including `n = len(objects)` is just setting up the abstract implementation.

Comment: Is order important?

Comment: @Peilonrayz  Order isn't important